# bluemix container cannot add user-defined service and Watson service together

Tags: dialog, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have created a user-defined service (Compose Mongo DB) and Watson Dialog Service.  I want to bind both services to my app deployed in IBM Container, however, I am not able to do.

I tried these, but none works:

1. I tried using `BIND_TO`, but I can only bind 1 service  (e.g. Use comma separated using UI -  `BIND_TO : MongoBridge, WatsonBridge`)
2. When I create bridge CF with 2 services bind, it doesn't work either (e.g. Using UI -  `BIND_TO : MongoWatsonBridge` where MongoWatsonBridge has user-defined Mongo service -  just URL - & Watson Dialog service bind)
3. When I tried to `BIND_TO` user-defined, + Watson service with --env CCS_BIND_SRV, it doesn't work either (e.g. `BIND_TO : MongoWatsonBridge`, also `--env CCS_BIND_SRV=Watson-Dialog-Service`)

Of course, user-defined doesn't work with `--env CCS_BIND_SRV=MongoBridge` - Bluemix throws error

I can individually bind each service though (using `BIND_TO` for MongoBridge, using `--env CCS_BIND_SRV=Watson-Dialog-Service`)

Please let me know if it is supported, or it is a bug that it suppose to work, but not working, or there is other way to bind both services.

Answer (score 0):

the user-defined service does not support service key generation so it cannot be bound using the "CCS_BIND_SRV" parameter. The only way you can bind both these services to the container is by using a CF bridge app. Create a CF bridge app and bind both these services (user-defined and Watson) to this app. Then bind this app to the container using the "CCS_BIND_APP=" environment variable in the command line.