# Connecting IBM Containers (Dockers) to Watson IoT service instance

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I wonder if I can connect my Dockers running in IBM Containers service with a Watson IoT service instance (of course, running in the same organization and space).

I can always assign a public IP to my Docker and connect through the public IP but I think that makes no sense and there is an alternative like I do with other services using something like

```
-e "CCS_BIND_SRV=My-IoT-Service"
```

when starting the Docker.

Comment: A possible solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607115/bluemix-container-cannot-add-user-defined-service-and-watson-service-together

Answer (score 0):

basically you can directly connect to IBM Watson IoT from your docker container. All you need to know are a couple of credentials. You can either obtain those by reading the VCAP_SERVICES JSON property which can be injected into your container:

Here is a [link](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/07/simplifying-distributed-docker-applications/) explaining this. (Search for VCAP_SERVICES)

What you also can do is just obtain the credentials from the Bluemix UI and use them accordingly.

Here a [python example](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python) how to do this

Finally, I can recommend [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/developer-iot) since it explains all on connectivity in detail